# Is it possible to make a usb removable drive identify itself as an another kind of device?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

Is it possible that we change our usb removable drive to show up as an hdd or a tape device?
How does windows for example detects and recognizes a usb device as a removable drive and not a keyboard? and differentiate it from other kind of devices as well?
what do i need to change this behavior if possible ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/42022/how-does-usb-device-recognition-work

Comment: You'd most likely need to modify the device firmware to make it identify as anything else. Some devices allow that, while most cheap devices won't.

Comment: in that case, will the device continue to work like before? i mean windows driver simulates hdd in order to access files or folders in a usb removable drive FAT, when the device is shown like hdd will it crash? what happens?